# python3 can participate to Ubuntu app showdown?

Tags: python, application-development, internet, qt, source-code

my application works only with python3 and it use QT, can I participate to Ubuntu Application showdown?

Right now I don't know how to create the package... Quickly doesn't work with python3

Comment: These are serveral questions and not really related to Ubuntu (the operating system). You should ask on the showdown site for the part of your question regarding py3 and qt. How to generate a package for py3 in quickly (or otherwise) is a separate question that you should ask here separately. Thanks.

Comment: @con-f-use This question has a good answer, no need to close it.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, you can participate.

Quickly is not necessary to participate in the Ubuntu App Showdown, but make sure that required Python 3.x dependencies are present in the default repository of Ubuntu 12.04.

The rules are [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/). You will need to upload your app to launchpad and create a PPA.